# Как подключить отдельный файл css через тег <script> в html

Tags: javascript, css, кроссбраузерность

Проблема с кроссбраузерностью в опере. Подключаю через этот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.opera) {
      document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='opera.css'/>");
  }
</script>
```

..но ничего не работает. В чем может быть проблема? Может знаете другие скрипты для подключения css файла.
Спасибо.

Comment: Для каких версий браузера вы подключаете отдельный файл?

Comment: @Alica если Вам помог како-либо из ответов отметьте его решением(галка под цифрой слева от вопроса).

Answer (score 2):

Ответ уже поднимался [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998293/how-to-determine-the-opera-browser-using-javascript)

> Opera 16 не поддерживает больше window.opera

Используйте объект `navigator`.

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera");
Проверка
var Opera = (navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera|OPR\//) ? true : false);
alert(Opera);
```

Comment: В вопросе не говорится, что речь о новой Опере. К тому же, наличие в ней таких проблем, чтобы приходилось подключать отдельный файл стилей, весьма сомнительно.

Comment: Объект navigator к сожалению не подключает отдельный файл сss.

Comment: @Qwertiy в вопросе ничего не сказано про версию, предоставлен лишь вопрос по ошибке, на который был дан ответ.

Comment: @AlisaTrushyna уточните пожалуйста версию Opera, которую Вы используете.